# "Allow Outgoing Connections" in Mac OS X Client?

Tags: security, mac-osx, firewall, osx-leopard

System Preferences > Security > Firewall only gives you the option to "Allow Incoming Connections" to applications of your choice. My understanding is that Mac OS X does not have a *built-in* way to block "Outgoing Connections" on a per application basis.

What software have you installed on clients to provide this functionality, and how well/poorly has it functioned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ipfw` is installed by default and you can customize the rules if necessary to block outgoing connections. There are some GUIs available to customize `ipfw` available (eg. [WaterRoof](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/index.html) or [NoobProof](http://www.hanynet.com/noobproof/index.html) by the same developer for a simpler experience)

For the most user friendly I use and recommend [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) hands down. I've been using it for years and it's excellent. The Network Monitor feature can be very useful but is quite RAM hungry.

Comment: I wanted to revisit this post, although its nearly a year old, simply to say I am a total Little Snitch fan boy now. Love it. Couldn't live without it

Answer (score 1):

[Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/), by far, the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn how to [configure the BSD "ipfw"](http://www.ibiblio.org/macsupport/ipfw/) if you wanted to use only built-in software.  Or you could install something 3rd party such as [Little Snitch](http://obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Little Snitch](http://obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) every time. Cost-effective, easy to set up and does exactly what you need it to.